# Refreshing a binded DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex

I have a problem..I am binding an array collection to a datagrid in flex. My problem is whenever i try to remove an item from the array collection.. the datagrid does not refresh the values....This is the code that I am using

```
coinCount = coinCount - showArray.getItemAt(eventsList.selectedIndex).eventcost;
                pendingEventListArray.addItem(showArray.getItemAt(eventsList.selectedIndex));

showArray.removeItemAt(eventsList.selectedIndex);

showArray.refresh();
```

eventsList is the datagrid that is bounded to `showArray`(an Array Collection)

Comment: Please post more code.  Try to write just a quick test application with just a DataGrid with an ArrayCollection to see if it works.  If not, post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Is your showArray declared as Bindable?
- Refresh is used to refresh a filter on an ArrayCollection. Use `showArray.dispatchEvent(new Event(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE)`, or `showArray.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.CHANGE)`...

Comment: yes showArray is declared bindable in the actionscript..I tried copy pasting the dispatch event to my code but nothing happens..it is still the same...

Comment: You shouldn't need to dispatch anything extra to refresh.  ArrayCollection does that automatically.